# Use Ionic v1.3 to build iMessage sticker app

Tags: ios, angularjs, ionic-framework, imessage-extension

I am new in iMessage app and apparently no idea about Objective C or other C things.

Can I create an iMessage stickers app with ionic?

I have couple of searchings but seems nobody did ask it before.

Any idea, guys?

Answer (score 0):

Ok for those who were noob like me. Here is the absolute answer.
Hope it help

[Easiest way to make an imessages extention for ios](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/tutorials/building-sticker-packs/)